# modular asp.net mvc application with nuget

Tags: asp.net-mvc, module, nuget, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Asp.Net-MVC application, that consists of multiple modules. Every module is realized as a separate project. I use the following folder-structure so that my files are copied into the areas-folder of my main-application.

```
<files>
    <file src="Views\*.*" target=".\content\Areas\Home\Views\Home\" />
    <file src="Views\Shared\*.*" target=".\content\Areas\Home\Views\Shared\" />
    <file src="Controllers\*.*" target=".\content\Areas\Home\Controllers\" />
    <file src="Models\*.*" target=".\content\Areas\Home\Models\" />
    <file src="*AreaRegistration.cs" target=".\content\Areas\Home\" />
</files>
```

The following post-build event ensures, that the 'module' is wrapped into a nuget-package and put into a local folder where all my modules' nuget packages are being dropped.

```
cd $(ProjectDir)
nuget pack -OutputDirectory $(SolutionDir)ModulePackageSource\
```

My manifest uses the assembly-version ($version$ variable which is "1.0.*") as versioning for the package.
So far so good but i was wondering if there is any better approach of doing this?

When a developer changes something (lets say he modifies a controller or a view) then he has to rebuild the project so the post-build event is triggered and the nuget-package is put into our "ModulePackageSource" folder (where we collect our module-packages). Then we use the following pre-build event to update all packages of our personal repository ("ModulePackageSource") to get the new versions into my main-application.

```
cd $(ProjectDir)
nuget update packages.config -Source $(SolutionDir)ModulePackageSource\ -FileConflictAction Ignore -NonInteractive
```

I read in a blog, that one should check in all nuget-packages (located in the "packages" folder) - but when i do this my folders get polluted real hard (as it adds the whole content of the module on every single build).
Problems: 
=> This results in big changesets for tiny changes
=> The whole stuff has to be stored to TFS
=> When another user checks out the source (GetLatestVersion) and just builds the whole solution, every module gets created newly (new version).

Is there a better way to do it, or is it better to first develop within the main-app and only put it into a separate project when the major-development is done?